# Create std::vector with brackets for default size

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    static const unsigned TOTAL = 4;

    std::vector<int> v[TOTAL];

    v[2].push_back(37);

    //std::cout << v.size(); error 
    std::cout << v[0].size();
    std::cout << v[2].size();

    return 0;
}
```

Is is valid to instatnitate `std::vector` with bracket like in the code above?

MSVS and ideone compile it just fine, but vector is messed up (see error line).

I know I can use `resize`, but what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a `TOTAL` sized array of vectors.

What you need is

```
 std::vector<int> v(TOTAL);
```

This constructs a vector with `TOTAL` zero-initialized `ints`.

Then,

```
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl; // prints 4
std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;     // prints 0
```

and so on.

Comment: And `v.push_...` instead of `v[2].push_...`

Answer (score 1):

**It is valid to instantiate `std::vector` with bracket like in the code, but with different meanings.**

```
std::vector<int> v[TOTAL];
```

Here you defined a vector `v` of `size=TOTAL`, each element of which is a `vector<int>`. Initially, these `TOTAL` `vector<int>`s are all empty (i.e. `size=0`).

After you call `v[2].push_back(37);`, `v[2]` will become a `vector<int>` of `size=1` with a value `37` in it.

So the output you for the following will be `0` and `1`.

```
std::cout << v[0].size();
std::cout << v[2].size();
```

---

If you want to call `size()`, you should call `v[i].size()` or define it as `vector<int> v(TOTAL);` (`v` is a vector of `size=TOTAL`, each element of which is an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can use resize, but what is going on here?

you are basicly creating an array of type `std::vector<int>`, just as in here:

```
int arr[TOTAL];
```

> Is is valid to instatnitate std::vector with bracket like in the code above?

you can have an array of vectors, but from your post it is not what you are after.

If you want to give your vector some initial size then use

```
std::vector<int> v(TOTAL);
```

this will set initial size of your vector to TOTAL, and value initialize all elements (set them to zero).

But you might actually want to:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(TOTAL); // this is not necessary
// v.size() is zero here, push_back will add elements starting from index 0
```

because in case of `std::vector<int> v(TOTAL);` your push_back will start adding from index TOTAL.